# Is it possible to center the dropdown below a pill (Bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So now I finally got my pill dropdown working but another question then arose - as I use nav-justified to center my navbar, the pills are quite wide and the dropdown is all the way to the left of the pill. Can I center this dropdown in any way?
The JSFiddle looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/htsda5xo/1/

A snippet of the HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">WEBDESIGN <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">HTML 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bootstrap 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">DYNAMIC WEBDESIGN</a></li>
```

Comment: Since the anchor has a padding of 15px to its left and right, you will have to give the ul.dropdown-menu a margin of 15px to its left and right

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  .nav-justified>.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    /* top: auto; */
    left: 50%;}
```

Comment: Slothice, happy to hear it's working, could you please encourage me with a +1 or right answer 'tick'?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<div class="nav">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">WEBDESIGN <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu text-center" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">HTML 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bootstrap 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">DYNAMIC WEBDESIGN</a></li>
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference... Thanks for your answer, however :')

Comment: surround the <li> elements with a div with a "text-center" class and try

Comment: That centers the text within the dropdown, but not the dropdown itself, unfortunately